# Content Grouping not working for me

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website which sells cloths under categories "Sarees" and "Dupattas".
I am trying to configure content grouping in Analytics, but it does not seem to be working.

e.g. I have set an extraction by page title /(.*[Ss]arees).*/
and some of the page which I was expcting to fall under this were:
http://dazzledori.com/Pure-Silk-Chanderi-catid-372030-page-1.html
http://dazzledori.com/Silk-Cotton-Chanderi-catid-372029-page-1.html

But when I go to my reports, I only see "not set" on the same page titles. Can somebody suggest if I am using this feature incorrectly, or there is gap in the regex? Thanks.

Edit: I just tried to convert my extraction into a rule.
So now I have created a single group called "Cloth products", and I created two rules inside it:
1) /(.*[Dd]upatta).*/
2) /(.*[Ss]arees).*/
Still not seeing any matches